# What is the difference between using setItem to set multiple state values and using useEffect to do so?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a reset button in my app that resets a few variables of my functional component:

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(0);
const [a, setA] = useState('a');
const [b, setB] = useState('blue');

<button onClick={e => ???}>clicky</button>
<button onClick={e => ???}>clicky</button>
```

There are two ways I could 'reset' the data: monitoring `selectedItem` for changes using `useEffect`, or have a handler that does so:

```
<button onClick ={e => setSelectedItem(e.target.value)} />
useEffect(() => {
  setA(Math.random())
  setB(Math.random())
}, [selectedItem])

or

<button onClick ={e => handler(e.target.value)} />
const handler = item => {
  setSelectedItem(Math.random())
  setA(Math.random())
  setB(Math.random())
}
```

What are the practical differences between these approaches? The hooks docs say to use useEffect for performing side effects, but I can't see why this approach wouldn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's important to consider the semantics of what you're doing. For example:

```js
<button onClick ={e => handler(e.target.value)} />
const handler = item => {
  setSelectedItem(Math.random())
  setA(Math.random())
  setB(Math.random())
}
```

this means that whenever you click the button you want the 3 state variables to be changed.

On the other hand:

```js
<button onClick ={e => setSelectedItem(e.target.value)} />
useEffect(() => {
  setA(Math.random())
  setB(Math.random())
}, [selectedItem])
```

this means whenever you click the button you want that one state variable to change and independently of that you want, whenever that one state variable changes, to change those other two state variables.

The real question you should be asking is what is it you really want to express with your code, given that it has the same end result. In short, what makes semantic sense to you? Does it make sense to say "this button can be used to change those 3 state variables" or does it make more sense to say "this button can be used to chanage the `selectedItem` state variable and this entire component will change the `a` and `b` state variables whenever the `selectedItem` changes?

It is usually important to make sure your code makes semantic sense so you don't land in the pitfalls of getting unintended side-effects when you make code changes. For example, if `selectedItem` ends up being changeable by other means, the 2nd method will ensure that `a` and `b` change at the same time. Do you really want that?

There's also a practical consideration. There's the `eslint` rule called [react/no-did-update-set-state](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-update-set-state.md) which states:

> Updating the state after a component update will trigger a second render() call and can lead to property/layout thrashing.

Layout thrashing basically means there's multiple potential redraws of the layout before a user can interact with it again. In the case of `useEffect` this can be an issue because `useEffect` is triggered after a layout update and setting the state might trigger another one. It usually has no noticeable effect on very simple operations but if you have a complex component hierarchy and end up re-rendering large portions of it then you will end up with a less responsive layout.

There's also the additional consideration that with the `useEffect` you also need to be mindful to avoid cyclical dependency changes e.g. `selectedItem` changes `a` and `a` changes `selectedItem` or makes a change which ends up changing `selectedItem` somewhere further down the line.

So overall there are three notes:

1. Use whichever makes more semantic sense for your component
2. Be aware of potential layout thrashing
3. If `useEffect` does make more sense take a step back and really think about why it makes more sense and whether there is a better way to solve your problem and at the same time avoid using `useEffect` to set state variables.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between these approaches?

I will try to answer this question in three points.

**Mental model**
You need to "think in effects". the UseEffect hook lets you perform side-effects that manly need to happen async like (fetch Data from API, manipulate the DOM).

based on that it's better to use UseEffect to handle side-effects so you are not confusing your colleges.

**Async**
You need to keep in your mind that useEffect is an async function but your event handler is sync function. That can lead to totally different behavior maybe you are not seeing a weird behavior here but maybe in other examples, you will start to notice that.

**React mechanism**
the last difference to notice it you need to understand React update state mechanism, react makes patches to update the state. That means in your event handler the three-state will cause one re-render because they will happen at the same time. In your useEffect that is not the case, you are updating one of them that case re-render then you are performing the effect that will case new re-render.

Maybe there are other differences but that what can I see right now.

I hope it’s a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few peculiar differences between the above two methods.

In the first method of using `useEffect`, you would be updating states `a and b` whenever selectedItem changes, be it by a button click or some other sideeffect such as a prop change. However in the second case, states `a and b` would only be updated if selectedItem is updated on button click and you would need to call `setA and setB` to update states everywhere you update selectedItem separately

Secondly, when you are using a useEffect  to update state, the state update will happen after updating `selectedItem`, however in the second case state updates doesn't gurantee that selectedItem is updated before setting the other states and hence if the other state updated depend on `selectedItem` value, you need to pass the updated selectedItem value to the other state updaters separately

In short, making use of `useEffect` is better when you know you have to take other actions whenever a state change occurs no matter how it occurs. Also its useful when you want to take action after a particular state is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the scenario you are referring to here is not really a side-effect, or I would say the side-effect react refers to. React refers to side-effect like if you are doing a network request
In your case if you just want to reset some variables I think having a clickHandler is the way to do, you would use a useEffect like if you want to do a network request when the component loads or some props change

Hope it clarifies